# PHP program always active in web-server

Tags: php

Is it possible? E.g. A script every minute write a word in a file (without the page opened in a browser).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you'd need to set up a [cron job](http://www.google.com/search?q=cron+job) that runs regularly (eg: every minute).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a cronjob.

Get some detailed info here:
http://service.futurequest.net/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=30

Plus you might want to ask your hoster how you can add cronjobs on your particular server.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of job definitely not for web server. The job for web server is to invoke your script on request from the web. PHP engine can run autonomously, without server. You can run it: `/usr/bin/php -f yourscript.php`, on Windows repace beginning with your `php.exe` path. Then use [cron](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-job-scheduling.html?S_TACT=105AGX03&S_CMP=ART) to schedule execution

Answer (score -1):

You can [execute php from the command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), in this case your scripts executes regardless of server/browser, you can use a for loop, combined with [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) to achieve what you described.